# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object with realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using realm to storing data after reading it from the server but when I try to store it in realm I got **"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object"**

here is my code of the method to storing data in realm

```
public void addOrdersToLocalDB(Order order,List<Product> products) {

    realmAsyncTask = myRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {

            Order localOrder = realm.createObject(Order.class, order.getId());
            localOrder.setName(order.getName());
            localOrder.setTimestamp(order.getTimestamp());
            localOrder.setDate(order.getDate());
            localOrder.setCost(order.getCost());
            localOrder.setProductNums(order.getProductNums());
            localOrder.setTime(order.getTime());

            Log.d("orders_data", "realm order : " + order.getName());

            RealmList<Product> localProducts = new RealmList<>();

            for (Product product : products){
                Log.d("orders_data", "realm product : " + product.getName());


                Product localProduct = realm.createObject(Product.class, product.getId());



                localProduct.setName(product.getName());
                localProduct.setBarCode(product.getBarCode());
                localProduct.setCurrentQuantity(product.getCurrentQuantity());
                localProduct.setStatus(product.getStatus());
                localProduct.setOldUnitPrice(product.getOldUnitPrice());
                localProduct.setImage(product.getImage());
                localProduct.setNeededQuantity(product.getNeededQuantity());
                localProduct.setTotalPrice(product.getTotalPrice());
                localProduct.setDescription(product.getDescription());
                localProduct.setUnitPrice(product.getUnitPrice());
                localProduct.setTimeStamp(product.getTimeStamp());

                localProducts.add(product);

            }

            if (localProducts.size() == products.size()){
                Log.d("orders_data", "realm products size : " + String.valueOf(localProducts.size()));
                localOrder.setProducts(localProducts);

            }



        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            HelperMethods.displayToastMsg("data added successfully to realm", HomeActivity.this);

            curvesLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //setupRecyclerView();


        }

    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {

            curvesLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            HelperMethods.displayToastMsg("data not added to realm, there was a problem : " + error, HomeActivity.this);
            Log.d("myrealm", error.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

I searched about that error and checked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144670/realm-exception-value-is-not-a-valid-managed-object) and still got the error hoping if any one can help?

also when I use other method with static data like the next code it works fine

```
   Order order = realm.createObject(Order.class, "1");
            order.setName("طلب 1");
            order.setTimestamp("٢٠١٩.٠١.١٦.١١.٢٤.١٦");
            order.setDate("٢٠١٩.٠١.١٦");
            order.setCost("1050");
            order.setProductNums("2");
            order.setTime("١١.٣٧.٢٦");

            RealmList<Product> products = new RealmList<>();

            Double unitPrice = 10.0;
            int neededQuantity = 5;
            int currentQuantity = 0;
            Product product = realm.createObject(Product.class, "1");
            product.setName("مناديل فاين");
            product.setBarCode("6251001214468");
            product.setCurrentQuantity("0");
            product.setStatus(1);
            product.setOldUnitPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice));
            product.setImage("https://www.albawaba.com/sites/default/files/im/pr_new/FINE_NEW_PACK.jpg");
            product.setNeededQuantity(String.valueOf(neededQuantity - currentQuantity));
            product.setTotalPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice * neededQuantity));
            product.setDescription("الوزن : 100 منديل / العدد : 36 علبة");
            product.setUnitPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice));
            product.setTimeStamp("٢٠١٩.٠١.١٦.١١.٣٧.٢٦");

            products.add(product);

            unitPrice = 7.5;
            neededQuantity = 10;
            currentQuantity = 0;
            Product product2 = realm.createObject(Product.class, "2");
            product2.setName("بيبسى 1 لتر");
            product2.setBarCode("6223001360766");
            product2.setStatus(1);
            product2.setOldUnitPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice));
            product2.setCurrentQuantity("0");
            product2.setImage("https://grocety.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/small_image/228x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/2/120-370x310.jpg");
            product2.setNeededQuantity(String.valueOf(neededQuantity - currentQuantity));
            product2.setTotalPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice * neededQuantity));
            product2.setUnitPrice(String.valueOf(unitPrice));
            product2.setDescription("الحجم :1 لتر / العدد : 30");
            product2.setCurrentQuantity(String.valueOf(currentQuantity));
            product2.setTimeStamp("٢٠١٩.٠١.١٦.١١.٢٤.١٦");

            products.add(product2);

            order.setProducts(products);
```

Comment: I really wish the error message said "you can only add managed valid objects into managed RealmLists" because that way people would know what the error message is trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `localProducts.add(product)` with `localProducts.add(localProduct)` , you initialized `localProduct` but forgot to add him to list, and instead adding product that not managed by Realm.